# How exactly cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object: work?

Tags: ios, performselector

I want to cancel the perform request registered for that particular target and method. 
e.g

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleSomething:) object:nil];
```

Will above method cancel my all perform selector Request used in project irrespective of methods?
OR will it remove only the perform request used in that particular class and for that particular method?

Please help me in understanding above concept.

Comment: I thnink it will remove target based means for particular class. From Apple Docs   **All perform requests having the same target aTarget are canceled. This method removes perform requests only in the current run loop, not all run loops.**

Comment: So if I have done something like
[self performSelector:@selector(handleBackgroundImplementation:) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0f];
In other class it will not get affected with above 
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleSomething:) object:nil];
cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cancels perform requests previously registered with the

performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

instance method.
All of the requests before executing this line.

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleSomething:) object:nil];
```